# EF Core EnableSensitiveDataLogging does not work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.1.1 using MySql and I have the following code to enable logging of the ef core translated to SQL Queries

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
      optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

I don't see anything in the logs though and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you tried call it in Configure services? Like this: `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging())`

Comment: Yes I tried that as well

Answer (score 28):

Using EF Core 2.2 with Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server, I was able to get the **EnableSensitiveDataLogging** option to work using the following configuration.

In your Startup.cs class,

Add the logging service to your ConfigureServices method.  I'm filtering the logging to database commands and information logging level,

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole()
        .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information);
    loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
});
```

Now update your DBContext to enable the sensitive data logging,

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection"));
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
});
```

Once you've configured your startup, you will now see the SQL commands and their sensitive data appear in our Output window in Visual Studio (Debug...Windows...Output) as shown below,

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) 
    [Parameters=[@p1='aaa' (Nullable = false) (Size = 450), 
                 @p2='bbb' (Size = 4000), 
                 @p0='New Column Value' (Size = 4000)], 
    CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyTableName] SET [MyColumnName] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1 AND [OtherColumn] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

It took me a while to figure this out as well.  I could not get the sensitive data to appear in the log using the OnConfiguring in the DBContext class either.

Hope this helps even though it's using SQL Server and not MySQL.

**NOTE!**  Be sure to disable sensitive data logging when deploying to production.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I have looked for this "Correct" "Working" answer for soo long. Every other configuration I have done may work, BUT I get the error that it is instantiating the loggin object on EVERY request. And for an API, that gets to be a LOT!

Comment: **RE: Be sure to disable sensitive data logging when deploying to production.**

You can enable it conditionally, like: 
`if (env.IsDevelopment()) { options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); }` 
for Web (ASP.NET) applications, then `env` is `IWebHostEnvironment`.

OR, for example with Azure Functions: 
`if (builder.GetContext().EnvironmentName == "Development") { options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); }`

Assuming you use Startup.cs and get the IFunctionsHostBuilder in your Configure method, through Dependency Injection.

Comment: In .NET 6, you need: `options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment());`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the application's LoggerFactory when building the options.

Don't forget to install Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (Nuget Package)

```
new ServiceCollection()
.AddTransient(provider => {
                var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                .UseLoggerFactory((ILoggerFactory)provider.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory)))
                .UseMySql(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                    .Options;
                return new MyDbContext(options);
            })
```