# How can I see the parameters passed to an EF Core query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know how to [show underlying SQL query in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893732/how-do-you-show-underlying-sql-query-in-ef-core). But what that shows me is like:

```
UPDATE [tow_base] 
SET [speed] = @p75, 
    [date_last_modified] = @p76, 
    [miles_per_division] = @p77, 
    [owner_user] = @p78
WHERE [tow_id] = @p81;
```

That particular query was generated in `context.SaveChanges()`, so I am not directly setting the parameters.

I can execute that query in any SQL client, with the values I *think* are in there, and it works. There are also value converters involved in many of those fields, which means the values I have stored in the record being updated are not going to be the same types as the parameters passed to the database `UPDATE` statement.

Is there any way I can see exactly what those `@p` variables are (particularly their declared type)?

Comment: [EnableSensitiveDataLogging()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826407/10646316) when configuring `DbContextOptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` when configuring your DB context like this:

```
services
 .AddDbContext<ContactsContext>(options =>
 {                         
   options.UseSqlServer(/*whatever*/);
   options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
 });
```

But be aware not to share these logs around, it's better to wrap the call of `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` in `#if DEBUG` or `if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())`.

Comment: I thought `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` was already the default in `Development`. After all, when you get a stack trace in production, it _suggests_ using `EnableSensitiveDataLogging`

Comment: Indeed, you're right. This is showing me exactly what I wanted (I'm not sure it's showing me what I _need_ -- at least at first glance the numbers look right, but that just means I'm looking in the wrong place!)